# Using XmlWriter.Create(), how do I get it to not overwrite the file it is creating?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xmlwriter

I am using VB XmlWriter.Create() to get a writer instance then write the XML, but once the XML file is created, when I run the program a second time it overwrites the file it created.  How do I get it to create a new file each time the program is ran?  Also is there a way that I could name the file as whatever the user enters as their consumer ID? so take the text from the txtConsumerID and name the file as what they enter in this textbox?

```
     Imports System

     Imports System.Xml
```

`Public Class Form1  

 Private Sub saveXML_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles
 saveXML.Click  

    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()  
    settings.Indent = True  

    ' Initialize the XmlWriter.
    Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\Documents and
    Settings\kck\Desktop\Notification.xml", settings)  

    With XmlWrt  

        ' Write the Xml declaration.
        .WriteStartDocument()  


        ' Write the root element.
        .WriteStartElement("PIAlertMonitor")  


        .WriteStartElement("ConsumerID")
        .WriteString(txtConsumerID.Text.ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()  

        .WriteStartElement("MaxAlerts")
        .WriteString(MaxAlerts.Text.ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()  

        .WriteStartElement("Notification")  

        .WriteStartElement("MailTo")  

        .WriteStartElement("eMail")
        .WriteString(txteMail.Text.ToString())
        .WriteEndElement()  


        ' The end of this person.
        .WriteEndElement()  

        ' Close the XmlTextWriter.
        .WriteEndDocument()
        .Close()  

    End With  

    MessageBox.Show("XML File Saved")  


End Sub`

End Class

Comment: Use a different file name each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file name dynamically every time by adding time stamp to the file name as following

**C:\Documents and Settings\home\Desktop\Notification_[current_system_time_stamp].xml**

to avoid replacing the existing file.